# Simple way to retrieve a text value using javascript/jquery (not prompt)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, sharepoint

I currently have a code using prompt(), but this displays several things my users don't want in their interface ("__.com is requesting information" appears at the top, and "Script Block" appears as a sort of title). `jAlert` (or at least the version I found) is too outdated for my SharePoint site, and `impromptu.js` conflicts with a css file on my site (which I don't have direct access to) and appears almost entirely transparent (I haven't changed the opacity).

I looked into dialog from jquery ui based on this example: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form  , but it seems overly convoluted when all I need to do is return a text value to a global variable..  I noticed that it requires creating buttons and input fields outside of the prompt, but I'm not sure how they're hiding these (and if css is required, I'm unfortunately not able to use this). Also, I would like to look at the API here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/  but the page is blocked for me on my network. Is there another area from which to look at the api?

Comment: Here's a very naive/minimal approach: http://jsfiddle.net/KxbB6/

Comment: Try http://jqapi.com/ for API access

Comment: jQuery dialog doesn't need to be "convoluted". It's probably a good solution, in fact. Seems like your real problem is your employer's absurd network policy.

Answer (score 1):

This will save the input to a public variable as the user types.
Also, when the user clicks the button it will show the information stored in the variable.

And as for the problem accessing the API information, try using a proxy from http://hidemyass.com And that should allow you to view the website off of your network.

```
<script>
var someVar = "";
function saveInfoToVar(info) {
someVar = info;
}

function showVar() {
alert(someVar);
}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeyup="saveInfoToVar(this.value)" />
<button onclick="showVar()">Show Variable Value</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Are there other resources required? http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Gc34Y/

Comment: I don't know why that is not working but when I use it on my computer in a basic html file it works fine. Try just making an HTML file and testing it.

Comment: Strange. It does for me, too. The other problem is that the dialog has a title of "JavaScript alert", which seems to be what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: JsFiddel may not allow popups off of their website. That's the only thing I can think off that would make it not work.

Comment: it's pretty easy to avoid the popup. However my method would require a very small amount of CSS which he doesn't want.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, he could just use Jquery's .hide() and .show() methods in order to hide/show a popup div